# How to sort textfile text in this way?

Tags: regex, sorting, awk, seq

I have a textfile contains below:

```
@_.5_sh
@handa12247
@lshydymhmwd
@ahmr0784
@f7j.i
@carameljeddah
@lnqm_iii2
@raghad.ayman.524
@asfhfdfgt4355
@kuw871
@nouralhuda_muhammad
@gogo56817gma
@kaald10000
@sal_0221
@kaled_24009165
@km_kn124
@princess.hana89
@fulefulemm
@norah.0._
@ommajed965
@lam3aastar
@alimarar265
@klthmlmdy
@anas.sasan55
@s.m_b.b
@asnosy_almgrhe_
@norh7132
@880ali7
@tv.creativity
@ksakking3
```

I'd like to sort them each 5 users in each line.

```
@_.5_sh @handa12247 @lshydymhmwd @ahmr0784 @f7j.i
@carameljeddah @lnqm_iii2 @raghad.ayman.524 @asfhfdfgt4355 @kuw871
@nouralhuda_muhammad @gogo56817gma @kaald10000 @sal_0221 @kaled_24009165
@km_kn124 @princess.hana89 @fulefulemm @norah.0._ @ommajed965
@lam3aastar @alimarar265 @klthmlmdy @anas.sasan55 @s.m_b.b
@asnosy_almgrhe_ @norh7132 @880ali7 @tv.creativity @ksakking3
```

i've played around seq, and awk, with failed attempt. i wish somebody who can help me out sorting this way.

Comment: @SeanBright I've tried that it doesnt work.

Comment: Sure it does. Maybe your file has `\r\n` line endings instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Confirmed that both of the answers (and the ones in the duplicate) work fine. Your actual input file must have `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: @SeanBright I didnt get it. show me example please. after adding \r\n - https://gyazo.com/b5cd23fea1f0848298b4737de7759613

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'ORS=NR%5?FS:RS' file
@_.5_sh @handa12247 @lshydymhmwd @ahmr0784 @f7j.i
@carameljeddah @lnqm_iii2 @raghad.ayman.524 @asfhfdfgt4355 @kuw871
@nouralhuda_muhammad @gogo56817gma @kaald10000 @sal_0221 @kaled_24009165
@km_kn124 @princess.hana89 @fulefulemm @norah.0._ @ommajed965
@lam3aastar @alimarar265 @klthmlmdy @anas.sasan55 @s.m_b.b
@asnosy_almgrhe_ @norh7132 @880ali7 @tv.creativity @ksakking3
```

It changes the Output Record Selector for every 5 Lines

Edit:  This does not work on dos format file, so run `dos2unix yourfile` before `awk`

Comment: It does it work either it giving me this format:https://gyazo.com/73af63d7b9234cdf2f63c58081979d53

Comment: @praser Not sure if you say it works or not.  Edit your post and add your data here, not just sample data.  Should work fine.

Comment: Post edited. please take a look. thank you.

Comment: @praser With your new data, my `awk` still works, same output as you requested.  Minor edit `" "` replaced with `FS`

Comment: for some reasons it does work https://gyazo.com/841d307ca62e5a73b58e9c5fb003c29f

Comment: @praser Try to convert your file from dos 2 linux like this: `dos2unix yourfile` before you run the `awk`.  If I go the other way around.  `unix2dos myfile`, it then fails, so file formatting may be your problem

Comment: you are right. I changed dos2unix and it works perfectly. THANKS!

Comment: @praser You are welcome.

Comment: It'd be clearer as `'{ORS=(NR%5?FS:RS)}1'`

Comment: @ed or `awk '{if (ORS=NR%5)  ORS=FS ; else ORS=RS} {print}' file` PS was not able to post multiline in comment :)

Comment: but then it wouldn't be concise :-)